# How to check if two randomly selected responses match?

Tags: r, dplyr, sampling

I have a dataset where 500 people, randomly answer 5 questions out a pool of 275 questions on a scale of 1-5.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(13)

df <- tibble(id = rep(1:500, 5), 
       q = sample.int(n = 275, size = max(id)*5, replace = T),
       ans = sample.int(n = 5, size = max(id)*5, replace = T))
```

My task is for each person, randomly select one of there 5 responses (of those that someone else answered too), and check it against randomly selected other person who answered the same question. If the two responses are the same I will mark it as true, and if not I will mark it as false.

I thought about approaching this by assigning everyone a chosen question based on those questions where more than one person answered:

```r
sampled_q <- 
df %>%
  group_by(q) %>% 
  mutate(n_times_answer = n()) %>% 
  filter(n_times_answer >= 2) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  sample_n(1) %>% 
  transmute(id, q, assigned = T)

df %>%
  left_join(sampled_q)
```

but from here I don't know how to approach the check. This is also inefficient because once I check one person's response, I've checked two responses so I technically could mark T/F for two people, although being efficient is not high priority for me.

I also considered reshaping my data:

```r
df %>%  
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, 
              names_from = q,
              values_from = ans) %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

but I've found this to be slow and I'm stuck here as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample 1 valid question from each answerer, then join that back onto `df`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(q) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(id) > 1) %>% # Keep only questions that have more than one answerer
  group_by(id) %>%
  sample_n(1) %>% # Keep only one question from each answerer
  inner_join(df, by = "q") %>% # Join it back on the main table to identify other answers to the same question
  filter(id.x != id.y) %>% # Don't include answers from the same answerer
  group_by(id.x) %>%
  sample_n(1) %>% # Keep only one other answer
  mutate(matched = ans.x == ans.y) # Check if the answers matched
#> # A tibble: 500 x 6
#> # Groups:   id.x [500]
#>     id.x     q ans.x  id.y ans.y matched
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl>  
#>  1     1   175     3   106     3 TRUE   
#>  2     2    15     5   117     4 FALSE  
#>  3     3   256     4   366     3 FALSE  
#>  4     4   268     4   194     4 TRUE   
#>  5     5   161     3   485     5 FALSE  
#>  6     6   100     1   390     4 FALSE  
#>  7     7   248     5   307     2 FALSE  
#>  8     8   126     5   341     4 FALSE  
#>  9     9    65     2    93     2 TRUE   
#> 10    10    48     1   461     5 FALSE  
#> # … with 490 more rows
```